# How to formally proof this measurability?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have

$Y = \int_0^t X_s ds$

It is intuitive that $Y$ is $\{\sigma(X_s), s \le t, \}$-measurable, since it onl y depends on the values of the process $X_s$ up until $X_t$ but how to write it formally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal F_t$ denote $\sigma\{X_s:0\le s\le t\}$ and let $\mathcal B_{0,t]}$ denote the Borel subsets of $[0,t]$.  If $X$ is bounded or positive, and if $\Omega\times[0,t]\ni(\omega,s)\mapsto X_s(\omega)$ is $\mathcal F_t\otimes\mathcal B_{[0,t]}$-measurable, then $Y$ will be $\mathcal F_t$-measurable, by Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: Thank you, do you know if that holds if $X_s$ is a Brownian motion, since it is neither bounded or positive, and I'm not sure if it is $\mathcal F_t\otimes\mathcal B_{[0,t]}$-measurable

Comment: The "bounded or positive" is just there to ensure the convergence of the integral. If $X$ is Brownian motion, then $s\mapsto X_s(\omega)$ is continuous on $[0,t]$, so $\int_0^t X_s(\omega)\,ds$ converges  in the sense of Riemann integration as well as Lebesgue.